# Selenium : Permission denied to get property Location.href

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm facing Permission denied error msg (Permission denied to get property Location.href)as the application moves inbetween Http & HttpS pages.

I have even tried using 
*chrome and 
by creating a new profile in FF

but still it produces the same error message

Can any one help me out

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 1):

```
             RemoteControlConfiguration rcc=new RemoteControlConfiguration();
              rcc.setTrustAllSSLCertificates(true);
              SeleniumServer seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
        try {
            seleniumServer.boot();
            seleniumServer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            //do nothing 
        }
        s.start();
        s.windowFocus();
```

Please Add Above first 3 lines of code to start selenium server and try... this is how i cleared ssl error in my project

Answer (score 0):

My biggest guess by the info provided is, that it's blocked by certificate on https.

What I did is installing Cybervillains.cer (delete it if not needed after the tests!) and keeping selenium server 2 run while testing.

This will handle the certificates.

I haven't tried if theres any better solution for the uptodate selenium 2 version.

Comment: What I forgot: Install the cybervillains.cer to your firefox profile and use this profile for testing!!